# Automate installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions via command-line

Tags: debian, package-management, software-installation, apt, virtualbox

How can I install [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) from a Bash script, in a unattended way?

Whenever I run `apt-get -y install dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms` from the terminal I'm presented with a interactive dialog, is there any way to safely bypass or pre-select the dialog choices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps